# Can you help me to expand this formula please

Tags: excel

Good Afternoon,

i have this formula in J7

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(I7),"YES","-")
```

As such the formula looks in cell I7, and if a date is present then it returns the word yes, if not it returns the symbol -.

What i need the formula to do is only display a result if I7 is not blank per say. So in effect the formula will only return a result if the cell has an entry.

Hope you can help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I7),"",IF(ISNUMBER(I7),"YES","-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula to check non-blank cell like

`=IF(I7<>"","YES","-")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer however the formula still shows the symbol - when nothing is entered in the cell I7, i need the cell J7 to be empty if the cell I7 is also empty, but display a Yes if a date is entered or the - symbol if that symbol is entered.

Answer (score 0):

or so

```
=IF(I7="";"";IF(ISNUMBER(I7),"YES","-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ISBLANK** function to check if the cell is blank.

1. If Cell is blank, output nothing
2. If not check if it is a valid number and output "YES" or "-" respectively

`=IF(ISBLANK(I7),"",IF(ISNUMBER(I7),"YES","-"))`